# Create or replace view error #1222

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1222

the code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `posts` AS  
    (SELECT '11' AS blog_id
        , 'blog1.domain.net' AS domain
        , '/' AS path
        , posts11.*
    FROM wp_11_posts posts11
    WHERE posts11.post_type = 'post'
        AND posts11.post_status = 'publish')
  UNION
    (SELECT '20' AS blog_id
        , 'blog2.domain.net' AS domain
        , '/' AS path
        , posts20.*
    FROM wp_20_posts posts20
    WHERE posts20.post_type = 'post'
        AND posts20.post_status = 'publish')
```

works with no error, this one

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `posts` AS  
    (SELECT '11' AS blog_id
        , 'blog1.domain.net' AS domain
        , '/' AS path, posts11.*
    FROM wp_11_posts posts11
    WHERE posts11.post_type = 'post'
        AND posts11.post_status = 'publish')
  UNION
    (SELECT '2' AS blog_id
        , 'blog2.domain.net' AS domain
        , '/' AS path, posts2.*
    FROM wp_2_posts posts2
    WHERE posts2.post_type = 'post'
        AND posts2.post_status = 'publish')
```

gives me the error

```
#1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns
```

the difference is only the id of the table, and all the tables or rows exits,
thanks for your help

Comment: Can you show us the structure of tables `wp_11_posts` , `wp_2_posts` and `wp_20_posts` ?

Comment: it's a wordpress multisite, all the tables are equals, sorry but don't understand what do you mean :(

Comment: The only difference that I can see between the two `UNION` is with `posts20.*` and `posts2.*`. The table **wp_11_posts** is the same so it should be between the tables **wp_2_posts** and **wp_20_posts**

Comment: Thanks, no, the error is when in a query there is one number and in the other two number, i.e. wp_8_posts and wp_9_posts, works, wp_8_posts and wp_10_posts doesn't work, the sequence is longer, from blog_id = 2 to blog_id = 20, if I do a query from 2 to 9 it works, idem from 10 to 20, all from 2 to 20 doesn't work

Comment: it seems that it doesn't work if the numbers are not in sequence,

Comment: Can you execute these queries and show me the result please ?
First one : `DESC wp_2_posts;`
Second : `DESC wp_20_posts;`
I just want to be sure we are not missing something.